# Format Json using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to parse this JSON using pandas and getting this particular error:

```py
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "ApiId",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "count_",
                    "type": "long"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "test 1",
                    654321
                ],
                [
                    "test 2",
                    32564
                ],
                [
                    "test 3",
                    185262
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
analytics_data = response_analytics.text
json_dict = json.loads(analytics_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["tables"])

cols_to_keep = ["ApiId", "count_"]

df_final = df[cols_to_keep]

df_final = df_final.rename(columns={"ApiId": "API Name", "count_": "Total requests"})

print(
    tabulate(
        df_final, showindex=False, headers=df_final, tablefmt="psql", numalign="left"
    )
)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\test\te.py", line 93, in 
df_final = df[cols_to_keep]

File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3461, in **getitem**
indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSpS.png)

File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1314, in _get_listlike_indexer
self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)

File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1374, in *validate_read_indexer
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['ApiId', 'count*'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

My goal is to create something like this:

```
API Name                            Total requests
----------------------------------  --------------------- 
test 1                              654321
test 2                              32564
test 3                              185262
```

How can I convert this JSON schema to a table? The data is exported using a REST API

Print results:

```
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df, tablefmt='psql', numalign="left"))
```

[image]

Comment: ```json_dict = json.loads(text_data)``` should it be ```text_data``` or ```analytics_data```?

Comment: It should be `analytics_date`. Updated the code and the error. Thanks @Owenn

Comment: You could try to use ```df.columns``` to see what are the column name that exists in the dataframe, and you could use ```rename()``` to rename those columns into the ones you want.

Comment: If you're still getting an error, feel free to edit the question and perhaps you could post the output of ```print(df)```

Comment: Added the new indormation to the code.

Comment: This does not look like a valid JSON. The 3 list items in "rows" key should be wrapped in a parent list.

Comment: @DivyeshPeshavaria Updated the JSON code.

Comment: @Amir in that case does creating DataFrame this way work for you - `df = pd.DataFrame(data=json_dict["tables"][0]["rows"], columns=[r["name"] for r in json_dict["tables"][0]["columns"]])` ?

Comment: @Amir I can post that as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your dataframe this way will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=json_dict["tables"][0]["rows"], 
    columns=[r["name"] for r in json_dict["tables"][0]["columns"]]
)
```